# Is it possible to setup MATLAB terminal

Tags: matlab

I have PC (Windows) at work. It has MATLAB 2017 with many toolboxes installed. At home I have MAC with MATLAB 2017 with few toolboxes installed. Is it possible to use my work PC as server and my MAC as terminal. I want to use toolboxes which are available at work. TeamViewer is not a good solution as quality of picture is bad-it is hard to work a long time.

Comment: Do you need to display figures? Or use the Matlab GUI? If not that you may be able to just use [PuTTY](http://www.putty.org) to SSH into your work PC from you Mac at home and [run the command line version of Matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlabwindows.html) (provided your company firewall and IT policy allow this).

Comment: Good idea! But with GUI it will be much more comfortable

Comment: You may be able to do something like X11 forwarding, but I have no idea how well that work on Windows or how performance compares to VNC or Remote Desktop. [This](https://kb.iu.edu/d/bdnt) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/119792/how-to-use-x11-forwarding-with-putty) might help.

Comment: I am sorry, but from my experience X11 forwarding is not suitable if you want to work in Matlabs gui, it is simply to slow. It is, however, sufficient if you only want to plot things. i.e. start matlab with `matlab -nodesktop`.

Comment: The best solution I found is Jupiter Notebook with MATLAB kernel